# FileNotFoundException using Eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I'm writing a Java class with Eclipse IDE. I try to read a file using this:

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("dictionary.txt");
```

The txt is in the same src directory of the file with this line of code. Filename is correct but it throws java.io.FileNotFoundException.
How can I fix it? Thx

Comment: When you launch your program, what is the *working directory* set for that process? It's one of the options in the launch configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the C:\ file location -- does it work then?

Comment: Same problem.. It works only if I don't use a IDE but a simple editor like SublimeText etc.. But I don't understand why

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention that you are trying to read fro relative path. To say that,

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("src/dictionary.txt");
```

OR

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("./src/dictionary.txt");
```

If your project structure is like this, it will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please try giving full path . 
I tried this in Windows .

```
 FileReader file = new FileReader("F:\\Java\\VD_program\\java_prog\\TestProj\\src\\main\\java\\com\\vish\\test\\dictionary.txt");
```

For Linux it will be '/' instead of '\'